# implode() new line not working?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to format a list of emails this returns with commas followed by a new line. I am new to php and cant figure it out.

```
$j = json_decode($s,True);
var_dump($j);
$emails = array();
foreach ($j as $a) {
    $emails[] = $a['Email'];
}
$file = fopen( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."emails.txt","w");
fwrite($file, implode(','+'\n' , $emails )); // <----- Right here, This doesnt wrk
fclose($file);
```

Comment: How is it not working? Provide what you are getting and what you expect.

Comment: Concatenation in PHP is a `.` not a `+` although thats just the first thing I saw

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP, not `+`. Additionally, new lines and other escaped characters need to be in double quotes otherwise they are considered literal. Furthermore, you can simply this by eliminating  the concatenation altogether and just put it in a string.

```
fwrite($file, implode(",\n" , $emails ));
```

Comment: Yours is great. Mine is a bit fuzzy at times. Must be getting old.

Comment: Shhheeeeesh tell me about it.